# Ruby socket troubles

Tags: ruby, minecraft, tcpserver, tcpsocket

I'm writing a Minecraft Classic server in Ruby called RMS, and it can currently send a heartbeat to minecraft.net just fine. But the problem is, when a client (in the form of a TCPSocket) connects, it will only respond to TCPSocket#read (so that the server may receive [the join packet](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Classic_server_protocol#Client_.E2.86.92_Server_packets)) when the server has sent [the server ID packet](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Classic_server_protocol#Server_.E2.86.92_Client_packets) or when the client exits. But the server ID must be sent *after* the server receives information about the player; it won't be the same content for every player.

This *might* be by design, but that's an odd thing to do...

---

You can find the current server software [here](http://github.com/awostenberg/RMS). Thanks!

EDIT: The exact problem is located in lines `99`-`101` of `program/server.rb`